# How do I use hook_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()?

Tags: views, 9

I'm trying to use `hook_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()` on a Drupal 9 website. I tried to put very simple command into the function in mytheme.theme and in a custom module; unfortunately it didn't show any *test* output.

```php
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables) {
  kint('test');
}
```

`kint()` works in `hook_preprocess_views_view()`, but I really need to use `hook_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()`.

I thought this is taking place because of some bugs in the core such as [Specific preprocess functions for theme hook suggestions are not invoked](https://www.drupal.org/node/939462), but that one is closed as fixed.

Does this preprocess function work at all?

Comment: Did you flush cache? Twice? Does the current page print an unformatted view at all?

Comment: Of course, I did. As I told I can get kint() working on the same page via other hooks. I thought all hooks are for all pages. How do I find our if the page can or can not print unformatted view?

Comment: @user102362 check that your [view format is set to unformatted list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPjB9.png)

Comment: Tat was it, @NoSssweat! I'll accept if you post as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Pass the object into the `$variables` array, and then in one of the Twig templates issue `{{ kint(var) }}`. Drupal might be using output buffering there, which would explain why you don't see any output when issuing those calls from the preprocess function.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The question is *Does this preprocess function work at all?* This answer doesn't answer that.